# objective c - getting null values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have been stuck on this for some time now but whats happening is that when the request comes back from mysql there is a null value but how do i check that a null value has hit my condition so that i dont store this value in the array. The code is below

The error i keep getting is -[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized and im trying to bind the array inside a tableview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

JobAddSiteAppDelegate *ja = (JobAddSiteAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bestitjobs.co.uk/appresults3.php", ""];
NSData *nsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: strURL]];
//NSLog(@"JSON: %@", nsData);
//NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
//NSLog(@"Result: %@",strResult);

//NSError *e = nil;
JSONDecoder* decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] init];
NSDictionary* listDictionary = [nsData objectFromJSONData];
NSArray* people =[listDictionary objectForKey:@"jobs"];

for (NSDictionary *person in people) { 
    NSLog(@"people %@",people);
    if([person objectForKey:@"position"] != [NSNull class])
    { 
            NSString *position = [person objectForKey:@"position"];
            NSLog(@"position %@",position);
            [tempArray addObject: position];
    }
}
self.listData = tempArray;


[tempArray release];
[listData release];
[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Error

2012-12-06 12:22:11.314 JobAddSite[7718:207] position Senior Network and Systems Consultant
2012-12-06 12:22:11.316 JobAddSite[7718:207] position SAP Business One / SAP B1 Consultant London
2012-12-06 12:22:11.317 JobAddSite[7718:207] position Business Development Manager - Market Leading IT Company
2012-12-06 12:22:11.318 JobAddSite[7718:207] -[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe565e8
2012-12-06 12:22:11.321 JobAddSite[7718:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe565e8'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00de95a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f3d313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00deb0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d5a966 __*forwarding*** + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d5a522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   JobAddSite                          0x000024cd -[ResultViewController viewDidLoad] + 604
    6   UIKit                               0x00389089 -[UIViewController view] + 179
    7   UIKit                               0x0038aa3d -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 63
    8   UIKit                               0x00386988 -[UIViewController _visibleView] + 90
    9   UIKit                               0x0062893c -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 354
    10  UIKit                               0x0030081e -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 954
    11  UIKit                               0x00588619 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 1381
    12  UIKit                               0x0038d65d -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 3478
    13  JobAddSite                          0x0000213f -[JobAddSiteViewController search] + 270
    14  UIKit                               0x002d94fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    15  UIKit                               0x00369799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    16  UIKit                               0x0036bc2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    17  UIKit                               0x0036a7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    18  UIKit                               0x002fdded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    19  UIKit                               0x002dec37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    20  UIKit                               0x002e3f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x01741992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00dca944 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00d2acf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00d27f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00d27840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00d27761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x017401c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x01740289 GSEventRun + 115
    29  UIKit                               0x002e7c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    30  JobAddSite                          0x00001dec main + 102
    31  JobAddSite                          0x00001d7d start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: what json formatter you used?

Comment: PREMKUMAR, im using JSONKit

Comment: It is also same like SBJson after get response all are same

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one:

```
if ([person objectForKey:@"position"]) {..}
```

This one is the same but maybe more readable:

```
if ([person objectForKey:@"position"] != nil) {..}
```

Comment: xapslock, still no luck the view does not want to switch after the for loop reiterates

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use the following code.

It is working Well.

[Download Supporting Files](http://www.mediafire.com/?nhp0bm636jsdzdi)

```
NSMutableArray *empArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];


NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bestitjobs.co.uk/appresults3.php"]]];

NSLog(@"GGGG:%@",request1);


NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:nil error:nil];



NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



NSDictionary *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];


NSLog(@"List Dictionary:%@",statuses);
NSArray* people =[statuses objectForKey:@"jobs"];

for(NSDictionary *test in people)
{
    [empArray addObject:[test valueForKey:@"position"]];


}


NSLog(@"EMP ARRAY CATEGORY:%@",empArray);
```

**Note: Before you Use SBJSon supporting files and import JSON.h**

**And check your console.**

Answer (score 0):

Check condition like this and add value to Array

```
for (NSDictionary *person in people) { 
   NSLog(@"people %@",people);
   NSString *position = [person objectForKey:@"position"];
   if(position) {
      [tempArray addObject: position];
   }
}
```